# Laravel flash messages fail

Tags: php, laravel, flash-message

I am using laravel 5.1 and flash messages. I want to show a flash message to the user when the validator fails.

My code looks like this:

```
/* 
    Validation
*/

$rules = array(
    'username'  => 'alpha_numeric_spaces|required|min:3|max:12|not_in:edit,password|unique:users,username', 
    'email'     => 'email|unique:users,email', 
    'password'  => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    'rules'     => 'required|'

);

$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    flash()->error($validator->messages());
    return redirect()->back()->withInput();
}
```

But I'm getting errors in flash message with bad text:

```
{
    "username": ["The username has already been taken."],
    "email": ["The email has already been taken."]
}
```

My problem is: I'm getting bad format messages.

"username": ["The username has already been taken."],

**instead of**

The username has already been taken.

Problem image:
[HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiBKC.png)

Comment: You will need to use foreach in your blade.

Comment: @Tommy,  if my answer was helpful, please upvote it and choose as best answer to thank me for my time.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `Session::flash` in your controller:

```
Session::flash('error', $validator->messages());
```

And `Session::get()` in your blade template:

```
@if (Session::has('error'))
    <div class="alert alert-warning" align="center">{{ Session::get('error') }}</div>
@endif
```

This should work, but if you still get **the exact same** error, try to iterate:

```
@foreach (Session::get('error') as $er => $errorMessage )
    {{ $errorMessage[0] }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. The problem is that I'm getting bad format messages ""username": ["The username has already been taken."]," instead of "The username has already been taken".

Comment: If you're getting the same object as in your post, added code should work. Please try my code and tell me if it works or not.

Comment: You can't get same message if you use `Session::` in controller and `@foreach` code in the view. You'll see another kind of error (because of wrong iteration logic) or it'll work, but you'll never get `{ "username": ["The username has already been taken."],  "email": ["The email has already been taken."] }`